# How to move file from one directory to another (Julia)?

Tags: julia

I have two different paths (directory path and file path). I need to move the file from one directory to another. How i should do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `mv` function.

```
help?> mv
…

  mv(src::AbstractString, dst::AbstractString; force::Bool=false)

  Move the file, link, or directory from src to dst. force=true will first remove an existing dst. Return dst.
```

One thing to note is that both `src` and `dest` must be complete paths i.e. if your source file path is `src = /home/me/file.txt` and you want to move that to be under the directory path `dstdir = /home/me/.julia`, the call should be `mv(src, joinpath(dstdir, basename(src))`.

(Just to be clear, the arguments can be absolute paths or relative paths, either works. By "complete paths" I only mean that both `src` and `dst` have to include the file name, `dst` can't be just a directory unless you wish you overwrite the directory itself.)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same in Julia, but for multiple files, so I wrote a function to do this incorporating tips from various people:

```
using Glob
function moov(stringpattern::String, fromdir::String, todir::String)
    frompath = readdir(Glob.GlobMatch(stringpattern), fromdir);
    topath = joinpath.(todir, basename.(frompath));
    mv.(frompath, topath, force=true);
end
```